How to Refresh a Feed When Returning from the Background in Android?
I want to refresh my feed in an Android app, but only when the app is brought back to the foreground (e.g., from the background or when the user minimizes and reopens the app).
The refresh should not happen when navigating between screens or activities within the app.
What would be the best approach to achieve this? Should I use lifecycle callbacks like onResume in the Activity, or is there a better way to detect when the app is returning from the background specifically?
If possible, please provide an example or suggest the best practices for this scenario.


detect when the app enters the foreground from background using onResume and onpause

This is my project using mine as a example
private var isAppInBackground = true

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (isAppInBackground) {
        refreshFeed()
    }
    isAppInBackground = false
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    isAppInBackground = true
}

private fun refreshFeed() {
   //TODO
}

